# Search & Replace in multiple document in Plone

Tags: plone

We are using Plone as a Document Management System in a healthcare environment. A lot of documents were already created and sent throught a custom workflow.

We now detected a small mistake that should be corrected in 171 documents.

Is there a method to change this programatically?

I'm thinking of something like VIM regexes...

:%s/wrong/right/g

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in feature for this.

You can try out these add-ons:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.searchandreplace

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rt.bulkmodify